Joyal's Cartesian squares
I am looking at Joyal's definition of cartesian squares Defn 1.1, Is this the same as saying that a commutative square is cartesian iff the induced arrows on the fibers are equivalences?

Yes, this is true: If the square is a pullback, then the induced map on fibers is an equivalence by the pasting lemma for pullback squares. The converse direction is slightly more tricky, but as Joyal explains you can reduce to the category of Sets, where this is checkable by hand.
